# JOIN two tables into array by key

Tags: mysql, arrays, select, join, grouping

I have two tables that would like to join into array with array for table2:

```
table1
id   value
----------
1    red
2    blue
```

and

```
table2
id   url
-----------
1    image1
1    image2
1    image3
2    image1
2    image2
2    image3
```

MySQL query is:

```
SELECT HIGH_PRIORITY * FROM table1
                  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
                      WHERE table1.id = 1
```

I'm expecting to have result like:

```
Array
(
  [value] => red
    (
    [url] => Array
     (
      [0] => image1
      [1] => image2
      [2] => image3
     )
    )

)
```

But it is always multiples table1 according to table2 entries quantity

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [value] => red
    [url] => image1
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    [value] => red
    [url] => image2
  )
  [2] => Array
  (
    [value] => red
    [url] => image3
  )
)
```

What should I change inside query to have desired array?

Comment: You could do a GROUP_CONCAT and you`d have your first array but with key 0 ='image1,image2,image3'

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM as opposed to InnoDB?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the associativity of the operators is opposite your expectation. Have you tried this:

```
SELECT HIGH_PRIORITY * FROM (
    SELECT table1.id, table2.url
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
    WHERE table1.id = 1
) data
```